# In TensorFlow, how to get all nonzeros of a SparseTensor row

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I need to be able to get all nonzeros with their indices and values of the nonzeros values. Have somebody done this or have any idea how please help me to get on the right track.

Is there a possibility that i can get all elements of a row in a SparseTensor (i know that there may not be any saved values for a row and therefore it returns null or none)